# MPmoviePlayer going black after updating to IOS 9 ( swift )

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, video, avplayer

[Solved] Hi my app used to load and play videos without any problem , as soon as I updated to ios 9 things went wrong. I am trying to make each cell has it's own sub view to play a video o touch.

My source code is to long but here is the part I am concerned about.

In the main viewcontroller :

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
                   let cell: CustomCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellTableViewCell

                    let videoURL = NSURL(string: Videos[indexPath.row].url!)
                    cell.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)
                    cell.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
                    cell.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
                    cell.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
                    cell.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
                    cell.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0
                    cell.moviePlayer.view.frame = cell.movieView.bounds
                    cell.moviePlayer.view.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(cell.movieView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(cell.movieView.bounds))
                    cell.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
                    cell.moviePlayer.pause()
                    cell.movieView.addSubview(cell.moviePlayer.view)
return cell
}
```

in the Custom cell class

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
class CustomCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var movieView: UIView!
    
    var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController!
   
    var videoURL:NSURL!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)
      
    }

 override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

This used to work perfectly before and now it's compiling without any error , but it's not showing the video , instead , a black screen.

NOTE : There is one thing I changed also , In the build setting I set Bitcode to NO , to get rid of the linker command failure !

**

> How I solved It ---//
>
> So all I had to do ,( NO CHANGE IN ORIGINAL CODE),  is to re-enable Bitcode for all builds ( Except for
> debug ) o get rid of the linker command. After that , I edited my
> info.plist ( Add NSAppTransportSecurity [Dictonary] with one Item
> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads [Boolean] = YES )
>
> That did it for me , now every thing is back to normal =)

Answer (score 1):

[From Apple MPMoviePlayerController Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html)

> The MPMoviePlayerController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9.
>   (The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is also formally deprecated.)
>   To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the
>   AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the
>   AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit.

You need to switch to using the `AVPlayerViewController`

[Link to AVPlayerViewController Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/)

For AVPlayerViewController

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: Videos[indexPath.row].url!)
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
    playerViewController.player.play()
}
```

Only the AVPlayer

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: Videos[indexPath.row].url!)
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = cell.view.bounds
cell.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

Make sure to add `import AVKit` and `import AVFoundation`

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. There isn't any incorrect information as far as I can tell

Comment: russel, I can't make anything to be shown: I want this code:
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: receivedURL)
        moviePlayer!.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
        moviePlayer!.view.frame = view.bounds
        moviePlayer!.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill
        moviePlayer!.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        moviePlayer!.shouldAutoplay = true
        
        view.addSubview((moviePlayer?.view)!)
        //moviePlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        moviePlayer?.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
        moviePlayer!.play()
to work